# Connecting server in root package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React app and here is my folder setup:

[image]

If I `cd src` and then run `node server.js`, I can see my server is running based off messages in added into `console.log`.

But when I'm in the root folder and I run `npm start`, the `server.js` is not connected.  Here is my root `package.json`, what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Try `"main": "./src/server.js"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run react app and server simultaneously, you can use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently). Install it, and modify your scripts section so you will have separate entries for `react-scripts start` and `node src/server.js`. Then you can run them both with concurrently. It will look something like this:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start-react-app": "react-scripts start",
    "start-server": "node src/server.js",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm:start-react-app\" \"npm:start-server\""
  }
}
```

This way, when you run `npm start` it will launch both scripts.